# Debian Litecoin Node Installation Issue

Tags: debian, litecoin

I have been trying to use [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/litecoin/comments/76dfbq/how_to_install_litecoin_core_litecoind_on_debian/) tutorial to install and run a full litecoin node on Debian that I can connect to a Laravel script and generate addresses with to no avail. How can I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: You should probably link to the tutorial you are referring to

Comment: updated question